# Populate textbox only with exact location using google-map api

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-maps-api-3

This is the first time I'm using Google map API and I am helpless at this point of time.

So, in my JSP page I am trying to provide a textbox that will suggest location dropdown when you start typing in it.

So, First I have included Google map API

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;
        libraries=places" 
        type="text/javascript" /></script>
```

Also, I wanted to restrict the country only to `India`, so I added below code in JSP -

```
function initialize(fieldId) {
    var options = {
        componentRestrictions : {
            country : "in"
        }
    };

    var input = document.getElementById(fieldId);
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

Other part of my JSP looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize('fid'));
    });
</script>

<input id="fid" type="text" autocomplete="on">
```

Now when I start typing into the textbox, I am getting expected result -

[image]

But when I select a place from suggested drop-down, my textbox gets populated with: `place, city, state, country`

[image]

I want my textbox only to be populated with exact location. In my example, I want the textbox to be populated only with `Powai`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details#PlaceDetailsResponses), the JSON returned by Google Places Details contains an array of objects called `address_components`.
This array contains parts of the address, such as postal code, street number etc...

It seems you're interested by the object where property `types` contains the value `locality`, this is the value you should put in your textbox.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (place.address_components)
    {
        for(var i in place.address_components)
        {
            if(place.address_components[i].hasOwnProperty("types"))
            {
                if(place.address_components[i].types.indexOf("locality") == 0)
                    $("#YourTextbox").text(place.address_components[i].short_name);

            }
        }
    }
```

Just replace `$("#YourTextbox")` by the ID of your textbox or use `document.getElementById` if you're in a pure JS solution.

Comment: I am getting error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined`

Comment: You have to replace `json.result` by `place`, bad copy / pasta, sorry ! See my updated answer